# Trouble using <cword> in mapping

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I'm trying to pass the word under the cursor to gtags and chain the definition search and the reference search together using a single function key.

My understanding is that this should work:

```
noremap <F4> :Gtags -di <cword><CR>:Gtagsa -ri <cword><CR>
```

But I get the following message:

```
Error: Line which matches to <cword> not found.
```

Just using `<cword>` should work. And using the following from [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/32.html) works fine and expands `<cword>` as I would expect:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :grep -R <cword> .<cr>
```

The word under the cursor is passed to grep and searched for.

I've tried `map`, `nmap`, `noremap`, and `nnoremap` (I understand the difference, I was just trying everything). I've also tried `<cword>`, `'<cword>'`, and `expand('<cword>')`. I've yet to find a combination that works.

The best I've been able to find is this:

```
nnoremap <F4> :Gtags -di <c-r><c-w><CR>:Gtagsa -ri <c-r><c-w><CR>
```

Which will get the word under the cursor and pass it to the definition search, but jump to the beginning of the line and pass that word to the reference search. For example, given the following with the cursor over `my_func`:

```
void my_func(void)
```

The QuickFix opens with the location of the definition of `my_func`, but then returns:

```
Error: Line which matches to void not found.
```

What is the proper way to map `<cword>` so that both commands are run? Why does `<cword>` work when passed to `grep` but not `Gtags`? Why does using `<c-r><c-w>` jump to the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<cword>` looks like a key code such as `<c-r>`, but it is not.  As such it is not expanded by `nnoremap`, but is expanded by `:grep` and a few other commands which take shell-type arguments.  `Gtags <cword>` does not work becasue `Gtags` does not know how to expand `<cword>`- this feature would have to be added deliberately to that command.  This is as expected.

The second problem is you need to expand `<cword>` once between the commands `Gtags` and `Gtagsa`, since the cursor moves after the first command (think of `nnoremap` as typing the sequence as you would type).

An alternative is to use `execute` to chain the commands together.  The pipe is escaped because otherwise it would be a command separator for the `nnoremap`.

```
noremap <F4> :execute 'Gtags -di <c-r><c-w>' \| execute 'Gtagsa -ri <c-r><c-w>'<cr>
```

Again, this is typed (and expanded) as you would type but the command action is delayed until the final `<cr>`.  Note, this is simple but will likely fail if the word contains quotes.

Another method is to use an expression map with `expand()`.

```
noremap <expr> <F4> ':Gtags -di '.expand('<cword>').'<cr>'
       \ . ':Gtagsa -ri '.expand('<cword>').'<cr>'
```

This expands both `<cword>`s at the time `<f4>` is pressed.

Comment: It seems that Gtags commands can't be chained with a `<bar>`. Typing `:Gtags -di my_func|Gtagsa -ri my_func` into the command line only returns the definition and not the references. While `Gtags -di my_func | Gtagsa -ri my_func` (spaces around the bar) returns `Error: Line which matches to my_func | Gtagsa -ri my_func not found`. Is it possible to add the ability to allow chaining using the `<bar>` to a plugin command as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144575)? Or do I need to use `execute()` somehow?

Comment: Ah, I was afraid `Gtags` would not play nicely.  The solution is to use `execute`  (command) not `execute()` (function).  Check if the updated one works; I can't actually test it because I don't have the plugin.

Comment: Both work. Only difference I can find is that the first method echoes both commands, separated by the bar, back to the command line. Whereas the expression map solution echoes the first command and then overwrites it with the second.

Comment: this sort of thing always trips me up!  Really great answer + explanation :)